# DNS redirect to a static IP?

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, url

I want to implement a URL shortener using a DNS modification. Is this possible?
It would do things like convert a domain name to a static IP:

```
https://fubar/keyword -> https://192.168.0.200/keyword
```

Ideally it would be a single word ''domain'', like fubar, not fubar.TLD.

Comment: DNS doesn't get path information, and you're gonna need a TLD if anyone outside your local network needs to use it.

Comment: Don't use HTTPS URLs with IP addresses instead of hostnames. You will have all sorts of problems even if you can have technically certificates based on IP addresses but it is rare, and you will mostly get errors.

Comment: If this is for internal needs, look/control at clients DNS configuration using either the search list at the OS level, or some kind of proxy at the HTTP level, through a Javascript file where you can control how the resolution happens.

Comment: More than one person needs to use this, and with devices that may not accept a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this for your own computer, or your LAN users, you can modify /etc/hosts to achieve this. For Windows, it will be somewhere in {WindowsOS}/etc/hosts

Comment: No, that won't work. Some browsers bypass /etc/hosts.

Comment: @nodnarbog never heard of that situation. What kind of browser are you using?

Comment: @BenL Firefox and Chrome both recently added DNS over HTTPS (DOH).

Comment: for https, it is not recommended to temper the traffic. https communication usually require the origin domain name to verify the authenticity. 
My suggestion is only for http communication.